# How to prevent filename overlapping on an image preview?

Tags: finder, macos

After upgraded to El Capitan, the image in Finder preview are overlapped by the filename, e.g.:

[image]

Is there an option to prevent filename overlapping image preview?

Answer (score 1):

i was just having the same issue and came across this question.

I think I solved it. Go to Finder > View > Hide Preview. Then click Show Preview, it should fix the glitch. Did for me. Good luck.